# How many $\alpha \in S_n$ are such that $\alpha^2 = 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

This is not for homework, but I am not great at counting arguments and would like some feedback.  The question asks

> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$. How many $\alpha \in S_n$ are there such that $\alpha^2 = 1$?

I know that, if $\alpha^2 = 1$, then either $\alpha = 1$ or $\alpha$ is the product of disjoint transpositions.

If $\alpha = (i, j)$ is a single transposition, then there are $\frac{1}{2^1 \cdot 1!} \binom{n}{2}$ such $\alpha$ (the $2^1$ and $1!$ are put in the denominator to help in noticing the pattern later).

If $\alpha = (i, j)(k, l)$ is the product of $2$ disjoint transpositions, then there are $\frac{1}{2^2 \cdot 2!} \binom{n}{2} \binom{n-2}{2}$ such $\alpha$, where the $2^2$ appears in the denominator to account for the cyclic permutations of each transposition, and the $2!$ appears to account for the permutation of the transpositions themselves.

If $\alpha$ is the product of $3$ disjoint transpositions, then there are $\frac{1}{2^3 \cdot 3!} \binom{n}{2} \binom{n-2}{2} \binom{n-4}{2}$ such $\alpha$.

Extrapolating from this, I find that the total number of $\alpha \in S_n$ such that $\alpha^2 = 1$ is
$$ 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} \frac{1}{2^i \cdot i!} \prod_{k=0}^{i-1} \binom{n-2k}{2}. $$

Does this look OK?  It looks like a rather ugly answer to me, so I have my doubts.  Any input would be welcomed.

Comment: Much studied. Perhaps you will find [this](http://oeis.org/A000085) useful.

Comment: For $n = 3$ your formula for the number of 2-cycles yields yields a non-integer. I think you are overdividing.

Comment: But then how many products of two disjoint 2-cycles do you get when $n=4$? I think you get $24/16$, which can't be right.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Perhaps I should take away the $2^i$ from the sum altogether?

Comment: Yes, remove it altogether.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795541/ for the same question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I was taught it, there are
$$
\frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$
2-cycles,
$$
\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{2^2 \cdot 2}
$$
products of two disjoint 2-cycles, and in general
$$
\frac{n(n-1) \cdot \dots \cdot (n-2k+2)(n - 2 k +1)}{2^k \cdot k!}
$$
products of $k$ disjoint 2-cycles, provided $2 k \le n$.

Comment: It looks like these correspond to $\binom{n}{2}$, $\frac{1}{2!} \binom{n}{2} \binom{n-2}{2}$, ..., and $\frac{1}{k!} \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \binom{n-2k}{2}$, so I was overdividing, like you said, by a factor of $2^k$ each time.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @tylerc0816, you're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

These permutations are called *involutions*.  The counting function for involutions on $n$ elements is documented at OEIS [here](http://oeis.org/A000085).  You'll be able to find explicit formulas, recurrence relations, asymptotics, and generating functions there, along with some references.  OEIS (Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences) is a pretty nice resource in general for finding what's known about various integers, especially if you can compute the first several terms to search for.